# Foreach is stopped when exception is caught in try catch block located within the loop in ASP.NET Webapi

Tags: c#, iis, asp.net-web-api

In my API I'm calling external SOAP API method several times. In order to achieve this I use foreach loop and inside it I put `try catch` block to handle exception and continue the loop. Everything works fine on my machine but when I deploy the API to another server running IIS it seems to stop calling the external API's method when exception is thrown as if the `try catch` was suddenly moved outside of the loop. Is it possible that it might have something to do with IIS configuration?

I've already tried putting this method inside another one and then putting that method inside `try catch` block but it didn't help.

```cs
public class Loader
{
    private static SoapClient client;

    private static string AddItems(Order order)
    {
        foreach(item in order.items)
        {
            try
            {
                client.SoapMethod(item);
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                // Log error and go to next iteration
                Log.LogError(e.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`Log` class uses Log4Net to put error message in a text file:

```cs
public class Log
{
    private static readonly ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger("API");

    public static void LogError(string message)
    {
        log.Error(message);
    }
}
```

In case the external SOAP API's method throws exception it should be skipped and it's supposed to go to the next iteration of the `foreach` loop to call this method with another data.

EDIT: I deployed my API to another server and it works there without breaking the loop so it seems that there's something wrong with that particular machine.

Comment: Perhaps `Log` is not configured properly on the server and that throws another exception. Or you have an `OutOfMemoryException` or a `StackOverflowException`.

Comment: I removed `Log.LogError(e.Message);` from `catch` block to check if it really throws exception but it still breaks the loop.

Comment: Then log the entire eception by using `e.ToString()` and show us that complete error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the comment of @Silvermind I found out what the problem was. Logs were also sent to Windows EventLog which threw `IOException` every time any application tried to save logs in `Application` source (from which a custom view was created). I googled it and it appears to be a known issue in all Windows systems from Windows 7 SP1 and Windows Server 2008 SP2 as described on [this site](https://www.tenforums.com/performance-maintenance/134570-event-viewer-mcc-exe-crashes-system-io-ioexception.html). The same error can be seen while filtering the `Application` view in Event Viewer.